# Python splat/unpacking/* operator on sets: is the result always sorted?

Tags: python, sorting, integer, operator-keyword, splat

Does the splat/unpacking operator * always sort when applied to sets of ints?

Example 1 (ints):

```
In [1]: [*{8,3,6,3,2,1}]
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
```

Counter Example 2 (strings):

```
In [615]: [*{'b','d','a','c','e'}]
Out[615]: ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

Counter example 3 (tuples):

```
In [1]: [*{(2,3),(2,2),(1,2),(1,1)}]
Out[2]: [(2, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not

```
print([*{8,3,6,3,2,1,108,109,255,569}])
```

gives me:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 108, 109, 569, 255]
```

You cannot sort sets. If you need to sort them you'll have to convert them to list or use a specific module like [sortedcontainers](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I guess I didn't try enough examples. Yep I can sort with `sorted(my_set)`.